# SFTP can connect but time out when uploading files

Tags: 16.04, ssh, ftp, sftp

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 last week, and I'm having a problem with uploading files via SFTP.

First I use FileZilla, then use BareFTP, I also try FireFTP (Firefox add-on), and the last one I use sftp command from Terminal. All have same problem, I can connect to server (my hosting, GoDaddy Managed Wordpress) but when uploading files, "timed out" (on FileZilla & bareFTP) and on sftp command "stalled".

I already tried to disable UFW, also changed FileZilla's setting back and forth between active and passive and limit connection to 1.

filezilla log

```
Status:    Connecting to <server>...
Status:    Connected to <server>
Status:    Retrieving directory listing...
Status:    Listing directory <directory>
Status:    Directory listing of "<directory>" successful
Status:    Connecting to <server>...
Status:    Connected to <server>
Status:    Starting upload of <path/file>
Status:    local:<path/file> => remote:<path/file>
Error:    Connection timed out after 60 seconds of inactivity
Error:    File transfer failed
Status:    Disconnected from server
```

sftp log

```
user@mchine:~$ sftp username@server
Connected to <server>.
sftp> cd <directory>
sftp> put <path/file>
Uploading <path/file> to <path/file>
<path/file>   0%    0     0.0KB/s - stalled -
```

after waiting (maybe because of time out)

```
<path/file>   0%    0     0.0KB/s - stalled -packet_write_wait: Connection to <ip> port 22: Broken pipe
```

I never had this problem uploading when using FileZilla on my last OS (Windows XP) and also have no problem when using AndFTP on my Android phone (and this is my temporary way to upload files now).

Can anyone help to fix this?